# How to prevent user from accessing JSON data from query parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask

I am developing a really simple webapp that searches for a company's stocks.

Here is the JS code (uses AJAX to fetch the company's stock from the server):

```
document.getElementById("requestQuoteBtn").addEventListener("click", function createQuoteRequest(){
    var quoteSymbol = document.getElementById("requestedSymbol").value;
    var quoteRequest = createAJAX();

    quoteRequest.open('GET', '/quote?sym='+quoteSymbol);
    quoteRequest.send();

    quoteRequest.onload = function getQuoteRequest(){
        if(quoteRequest.status == 200){ // SUCCESSFUL
            displayQuoteData(false, JSON.parse(quoteRequest.response)); // basically shows a hidden div with the data
        }
        else // NO COMPANY W/ THIS SYMBOL FOUND
            displayQuoteData(true, null);
    };
});
```

Here is the Flask code:

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def quote():
    requestedSymbol = request.args.get("sym")
    if not requestedSymbol:
        return "no symbol"

    quoteData = lookup(requestedSymbol) # USES AN API TO FETCH COMPANY'S STOCK

    if quoteData is None:
        return "NONE", 404
    else:
        return quoteData
```

**The issue** is that if the user accesses, for example, this URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/quote?sym=AAPL
```

It will literally show a raw HTML with JSON's data, instead of my website with the data:

```
{"name":"Apple, Inc.","price":"$245.18","symbol":"AAPL"}
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: If the browser needs it to function, the user can access it. The only way to prevent that is to never send it to the browser.

Comment: @KevinB That's true. The only issue I have is that, instead of displaying my website's template, it displays a raw HTML file with the JSON data in it =/

Comment: You could try to detect whether or not the request was initialized by ajax and return a different format... though i don't think that'd be worth the effort.

Comment: Use bearer token authentication with short-lived sliding tokens.  It isn't 100% but it does a good job.

Comment: If you want that route to reply two different ways, you could also use the `Accept` header; if that contains `text/html`, then you can choose to serve up a page with the data. If it doesn't, you could send the JSON. You'd have to make sure your XHR request only accepts `application/json`, though, or it'll also get back HTML.

Answer (score -2):

If you simply want to make sure that users do not accidentally access your api endpoint when trying to access your website (aka this is about user experience and your not concerned with adding auth to your API endpoint)

The easiest way is to create separate routes for your api and your client routing

Update:

```
@app.route("/api/quote", methods=["GET"])
```

Likewise update:

```
quoteRequest.open('GET', '/api/quote?sym='+quoteSymbol);
```

Your client routing will still be:

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET"])
```

If you want to make sure that nobody can access your api endpoint then you need to add some sort of authorization to your endpoint.

If you do not secure your API with some authorization then anyone can access the data you return from your server API simply by visiting the route.

Either way setting up separate routes for your API endpoints and client side routes should solve the problem of showing API data instead of your client template when visiting:

**mywebsite.com/quote?sym=AAPL**